# Auto populate a column to a different sheet if a condition is met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been trying to Auto populate a column onto a different worksheet only if an action is Ready.

If a file is marked as 'Ready' for scanning, it should auto-populate to a different worksheet with the patient name.

My goal is when I mark a patient as ready on the scanning column on the worksheet labeled as "week 1", it should auto populate on the worksheet labeled "Christine" with the patient name.

I have been trying to write an `IF` statement for the sheet labeled "Christine" but it types in the `IF` statement:

```
=IF(Week1!G2="READY", Week1!C2, " ")
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather simpler method; I've hosted this sample [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au6FcD8kvdA9kS4vJq4p_l5OlpZC?e=W9Dylp) in case you want to download (and modify) for your own use.

[image: Tab: Week 1]

**NOTE:** I used checkboxes for column G and linked to their respective cells (for which I changed font color to white, as to make "TRUE" or "FALSE" not be visible on-screen/-print).  This was just to make it look cleaner; it'd also be easier to down-size the column, in case the document needs to be print-ready and gets to be too wide to fit-to-page.  You can easily adjust the final sheet's formula to match your original "READY" as well if desired.  FYI, to insert these you need to enable the Developer tab in your settings.

[image: Tab: Christine]

Here, I specifically wrote out a formula designed so that you need only to copy the top-left-most cell...

`=IF(INDIRECT("'"&A$1&"'!G"&(ROW()-1))=TRUE(),INDIRECT("'"&A$1&"'!C"&(ROW()-1)),"")`

...then you can freely paste to all subsequent cells further down or to the right as you want/need.

Important notes about this formula:

- Row 1 acts as not just a header but also a formula reference per-column, which points to the correct sheet (therefore, sheet names need to match up with these)
- As-is, the current setup **will not** automatically populate contiguously; in other words, blank cells will remain on resulting sheet.  Depending on your usage and/or preference, this may or may not be desired behavior.  If you don't want blanks to appear in-between cells, this can still be accomplished ([example](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-remove-blank-cells-from-a-range)).  Let me know if you need help and I can modify accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

*You need an array formula to get Patient's Name as soon you fill respected cells with `Ready`.*

[image]

---

[image]

- Formula in Cell `B4` of `Sheet Cristine`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Week1!$C$46:$C$50, SMALL(IF(("Ready"=Week1!$G$46:$G$50), MATCH(ROW(Week1!$G$46:$G$50), ROW(Week1!$G$46:$G$50)), ""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

**N.B.**

```
 MATCH(ROW($G$46:$G$50), ROW($G$46:$G$50)), ""),ROWS($A$1:A1)))
```

Return the k'th smallest row number becomes,

`SMALL({"", 2, "", 4, ""}, ROWS($A$1:A1))`

- To make formula dynamic insted of search string `Ready` you may use any suitable cell reference of sheet Cristine.
- And this may be the part of the formula.

  ```
  SMALL(IF(($B$1"=Week1!$G$46:$G$50)
  ```
- For this you need to enter search string `Ready` in cell `B1` of Sheet `Cristine`.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Write your concern that why this has been down voted?